# Java Read and Write Spark Vector's to Hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I wrote Vector's `(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)` to the `HDFS` as the following

```
public void writePointsToFile(Path path, FileSystem fs, Configuration conf,
        List<Vector> points) throws IOException {

    SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf,
            Writer.file(path), Writer.keyClass(LongWritable.class),
            Writer.valueClass(Vector.class));

    long recNum = 0;

    for (Vector point : points) {
        writer.append(new LongWritable(recNum++), point);
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

( not sure that I used the right way to do that can't test it yet )

now I need to read this file as `JavaRDD<Vector>` because I want to use it in Spark `Clustering K-mean` but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark directly supports reading Hadoop SequenceFiles. You would do something like:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Vector> input = 
    sc.sequenceFile(fileName, LongWritable.class, Vector.class);
```

You then just need to convert the `JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Vector>` into a `JavaRDD<Vector>`.

```
JavaRDD<Vector> out = input.map(new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable, Vector>, Vector>() {

    @Override
    public Vector call(Tuple2<LongWritable, Vector> tuple) throws Exception {
        return tuple._2();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,  can you tell me please how to convert the JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Vector> into a JavaRDD<Vector>.?

Comment: I added a map function example to turn it into a JavaRDD